# Remote peer IP of Google Could VPN, GCP VPN

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

Does the Google Cloud VPN work if I don't have a fixed public IP as "Remote Peer IP"?

It seems a fix IP address is required when I create the VPN tunnel in GCP console.